# How can I update a password in a file using marker in ansible?

Tags: file, replace, ansible, passwords, updates

I have a set of properties files across multiple hosts. One sample file is below.

```
cat app1.properties
url=whateever
protocol=t3
envpass=whateverpass
port=7665
```

I wish to update the password using ansible.

The issue is the password variable in the properties file `envpass` may be something else in other files. Thus I cannot use the `replace` module.

So it could be anything in any file and may appear any number of times like below:

```
dbpass=xxxxxx
systempass=xxxxxx
password=xxxxx
pwd=xxxxxx
pass=xxxxx
```

I was thinking if it is possible to put a marker having the variable name `envpass` one line above the password entry in the properties file like below and use it to somehow update the password like `envpass=whateverNEWpass`.

```
cat app1.properties
url=whateever
protocol=t3
<!-- {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED PASSWORD variable envpass -->
envpass=whateverpass
port=7665
```

Desired output:

```
cat app1.properties
url=whateever
protocol=t3
<!-- {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED PASSWORD variable envpass-->
envpass=whateverNEWpass
port=7665
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

The [`replace` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) is based on a regexp, so you can use it to replace whenever the existing value is:

```yaml
- replace:
    path: /path/to/file
    regexp: '^envpass=.*'
    replace: "envpass={{ password }}"
```

If you want to be sure the password is set in the file, whenever the line `envpass` exists or not, you can use the [`lineinfile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html):

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: /path/to/file
    regexp: '^envpass=.*'
    line: "envpass={{ password }}"
```

This will change the value if the line already exists otherwise it will add it.

Comment: OPs problem is that there might be a number of other properties than `envpass` needing password update. Replace is probably still the way to go if those are known in advance (which should be the case for proper management anyway IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Building-up on @Zigarn answer.

I take for granted that, for proper management on the long term, you are in control of the list of properties holding the password you need to change.

As already pointed out, `ansible.builtin.replace` looks for a `regexp` in a given file. The `replace` string can contain back-references to matching groups in the `regexp`. It is then totally possible to build a regexp matching any of the known properties and replace the password everywhere needed.

Here is a demo playbook. I used an extra var with a default value for the password, you can change this according to your needs.

```yaml
---
- name: Change all possible password properties
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    password_properties:
      - envpass
      - dbpass
      - systempass
      - password
      - pwd
      - pass

    test_file: test.properties

  tasks:
    - name: Show our file before (possible) modification
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', test_file).split('\n') }}"

    - name: Modify the file if needed
      replace:
        path: "{{ test_file }}"
        regexp: >-
          ^({{ password_properties | join('|') }})\s*=\s*\S*$
        replace: >-
          \g<1>={{ new_password | default('oldpass') }}
      notify: file_modified

  handlers:
    - name: Show the file after modification
      listen: file_modified
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', test_file).split('\n') }}"
```

Which gives:

- First run on default content without changes

  ```
  $ ansible-playbook playbook.yml

  PLAY [Change all possible password properties] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

  TASK [Show our file before (possible) modification] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": [
          "url=whateever",
          "protocol=t3",
          "envpass=oldpass",
          "port=7665",
          "dbpass=oldpass",
          "systempass=oldpass",
          "password=oldpass",
          "pwd=oldpass",
          "pass=oldpass"
      ]
  }

  TASK [Modify the file if needed] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- Change the password

  ```
  $ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e new_password=brandnewpass

  PLAY [Change all possible password properties] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

  TASK [Show our file before (possible) modification] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": [
          "url=whateever",
          "protocol=t3",
          "envpass=oldpass",
          "port=7665",
          "dbpass=oldpass",
          "systempass=oldpass",
          "password=oldpass",
          "pwd=oldpass",
          "pass=oldpass"
      ]
  }

  TASK [Modify the file if needed] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
  changed: [localhost]

  RUNNING HANDLER [Show the file after modification] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": [
          "url=whateever",
          "protocol=t3",
          "envpass=brandnewpass",
          "port=7665",
          "dbpass=brandnewpass",
          "systempass=brandnewpass",
          "password=brandnewpass",
          "pwd=brandnewpass",
          "pass=brandnewpass"
      ]
  }

  PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```